# How to make a loop with webrequest to check for changes in response

Tags: c#, loops, response, webrequest

I am asking you today how to make a browser-like request, in a nutshell I want to make a web request to a website, keep it alive so I can check for changes in cookies and source code in a loop?

Here is my actual code:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.php");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // needed to keep the session alive

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        string value = null;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            bool search = true;

            while(search == true)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < response.Cookies.Count && search; i++)
                {
                    if (response.Cookies[i].Name == "test")
                    {
                        value = response.Cookies[i].Value;
                        search = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (value != null)
            Console.WriteLine("found cookie : {0}", value);

        response.Close();
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your entire code in a loop and remove the while loop you already have. 
If you want to check the difference between response by getting the entire stream and storing it or its hash somewhere then comparing it with the next response.
Please also remember to put a try/catch and that by default only two requests are allowed unless you tweak the configuration

```
bool search = true;

while (search == true) {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.php");
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // needed to keep the session alive

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string value = null;

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Cookies.Count && search; i++)
        {
            if (response.Cookies[i].Name == "test")
            {
                value = response.Cookies[i].Value;
                search = false;
            }
        }            
    }

    if (value != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("found cookie : {0}", value);
    }
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the thing is that the cookie I want to get is set after a specific amount of time that of course resets after each new connection so it won't work

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the cookie requirement? How is the cookie set? By what mechanism? My understanding of the HTTP protocol is that after the response is completed the connection is closed by either the client or server.  For you to accomplish something similar you need to use a polling type protocol like ws